# MyBatis issue with MSSQL, JTDS running in Tomcat

Tags: java, sockets, timeout, mybatis, jtds

I have a web service application (Apache, Tomcat, JAVA, Spring, MyBatis, jndi, jtds stack) that does many database queries.  Recently, we've been having DB server overload issues, where a complex query that normally takes 10-20 seconds is now taking 60+ seconds.

Aside from just being slow, what has started to happen is that when the query pushes the 90 second mark (almost exactly), the MyBatis layer pukes with the error: "java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Socket closed; SQL []; I/O Error: Socket closed; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: I/O Error: Socket closed"

I know the best fix is the make SQL faster; we're working on that.  In the meantime, any idea where the 90 second socket time-out is coming from?

From reading around it looks like the socket timeout for a jtds connection is default to 0.  I'm trying to set it to 10 minutes with this, but it does not change the error happening at 90 seconds:  url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://mydatabaseserver:1433;DatabaseName=mydatabase;sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false;socketTimeout=600"

Where else I can look to get rid of this timeout?

Thanks

Comment: We are running jtds 1.3.1 if that makes any difference.

Comment: IMHO your question has no relation to mybatis at all

Comment: Maybe not. I was not sure if there was a config in MyBatis I would set to help with the timeout.  I've been concentrating on the jtds configuration up to now.